# Range of strong limit of a semigroup belongs to the fixed space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators, strong-convergence

> Let $\left(T(t)\right)_{t\geq0}$ be a $C_0$-semigroup on a Banach lattice $E$ such that $T(t)$ converges strongly to a positive operator $S$ as $t \to \infty.$ Then $$T(t)S=S \text{ for all }t\geq0.$$

**My attempt:** I see why this is true is $S$ is a projection but I'm unable to prove it for the general case.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Consider $\|(T(t)T(s)-T(s))x\|$, use the semigroup property, and take $s\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows since $$\|T(s)Sf-Sf\|=\lim_{t\to\infty}\|T(s)T(t)f-T(t)f\|=\lim_{t\to\infty}\|T(t+s)f-T(t)f\|=0.$$

Comment: It is noteworthy that the argument above does not depend on the positivity of the involved projection. Nonetheless, it follows that $S E$ is a Banach lattice under a norm equivalent to the norm on $E$ itself.

Comment: @Yaddle, Yes I intended to mention it but forgot to.